# SQL NOT IN operator not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
        industries
        -----------
        + id
        + name

        users
        -----------
        + id
        + name

        teams
        -----------
        + id
        + name
        + type

        user_to_team
        -----------
        + id
        + user_id
        + team_id
        + industry_id
```

I am running the following sql query:

```
        SELECT teams.id
        FROM teams 
        LEFT JOIN user_to_team ON user_to_team.`team_id` = teams.id 
        WHERE teams.type = 'general' 
        AND (user_to_team.industry_id NOT IN(1))
        GROUP BY user_to_team.team_id 
        LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that it's returning teams that contain an industry_id of 1 in the `user_to_team` table.

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions the use of a GROUP BY clause is a little icky. While it may augment performance, in certain situations it can lead to unexpected results. Also, if you don't want an OUTER JOIN, don't use an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: it seems, you should add null check for industry_id.

Comment: @Strawberry I removed group by and it still does not work.

Comment: If you have only one value to compare better to use `<>`Instead of not in `AND user_to_team.industry_id <>1`

Comment: @hgulyan I dont understand the importance of checking against null it will never be null

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid No I might have more than one to check so im going to keep NOT IN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL`

```sql
SELECT teams.id
FROM teams 
  LEFT JOIN user_to_team 
    ON  user_to_team.team_id = teams.id
    AND user_to_team.industry_id IN (1)    -- caution: this is IN
                                           -- and **not** NOT IN
WHERE teams.type = 'general' 
  AND user_to_team IS NULL ;
```

or a `NOT EXISTS` subquery, which is easier to read:

```sql
SELECT teams.id
FROM teams 
WHERE teams.type = 'general' 
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM user_to_team 
        WHERE user_to_team.team_id = teams.id 
          AND user_to_team.industry_id IN (1)       -- caution: this is IN 
                                                    -- and **not** NOT IN
      ) ;
```

Comment: should the subquery be IN or NOT IN?

Comment: You code returns all teams that have related at least one `industry_id` that is different from 1. They have 1 or not, your query does not even examine those rows (that is what your `WHERE` does.)

Comment: Im still not quite understanding. I used a NOT IN clause so shouldn't it return the rows where industry_id is NOT IN 1

Comment: It didn't return those rows. But if a `team_id` is related to another `industry_id` (say 5), then that row (that is: team_id) is returned by your query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving that conditional check into the 'LEFT JOIN' statement for that table, after the 'ON' clause?

```
SELECT teams.id
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN user_to_team ON user_to_team.`team_id` = teams.id
AND user_to_team.industry_id NOT IN(1)
WHERE teams.type = 'general'
LIMIT 1
```

Also, do you have the correct data type for that column?

Comment: Correct... otherwise, the left join actually becomes an INNER JOIN

Comment: Disregard the industry_id in the teams table thats for something different. Focus on the user_to_team.industry_id field

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that any given team can be associated with more than 1 industry in the user_to_team table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT teams.team_id
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN user_to_team
  ON user_to_team.team_id = teams.team_id
    AND user_to_team.industry_id = 1
WHERE teams.type = 'general'
  AND user_to_team.team_id IS NULL;
```